# PHP Mobile Redirect Assistance

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

I am a webmaster and I am currently working on adding simpler versions of a few pages to create a sub-site for mobile browsers.  As such, I would like a redirect from the full site to the mobile site for users browsing on mobile devices and I would prefer to do this with PHP.  The one I have found has great reviews, but I cannot get it to work.  Every time I view the published index page (which is a php file), I receive:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mobile_Detect' not found in D:\Hosting\4872190\html\php\index.php on line 4

In the directory, I have the following files and folders: index.php,
mobile (folder),mobilehome.php (in mobile),events.php (in mobile), news.php (in mobile).

Obviously, users will enter the main URL of the site, which will load index.php, and that file will redirect them to mobile/mobilehome.php upon discovery of a mobile browser.

Below is the contents of two files for reference: index.php and mobile_detect.php (which I downloaded as part of a PHP class).

index.php

```
<?
include 'mobile_detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if(!$_SESSION['isMobile']){
$_SESSION['isMobile'] = $detect->isMobile();
}

if($detect->isMobile()){
header('mobilehome.php', true, 301);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"          
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />...
```

You can view the code for the mobile_direct.php class I downloaded by clicking the URL below.

http://www.troop322dc.com/php/mobile_redirect.html

What is causing the problem?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Try `new Mobile_Detect();` (with brackets).

Answer (score 2):

It is looking for / expecting mobile_detect.php to be in the same directory as index.php.  If it is actually in html/php/mobile/, then you want to do `include 'mobile/mobile_detect.php';`

Answer (score 1):

That is true, re check the file tree and see if the mobile_detect.php is on the same level. Remember to also start your sessions at the head of your file.